# plotting 2d colored grid (eg. pcolormesh) in 3d-plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, surface, imshow

I have got an array of surface heights `H`.
I want to plot the surface as wireframe and put the values as `pcolormesh` or `imshow` at the bottom of of the projection (eg `z=0`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

H=np.arange(0,100)
H=H.reshpae(10,10) # <- just as simple example

x,y = np.meshgrid(range(0,20),range(0,20))
fig=plot.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,H)
#plot 2D meshgrid here
fig.show()
```

Of course pcolormesh is for 2D only. But using `countourf` does not show the grid like structure. Varying stride didn't changed the contours at all.
I thought already about using `plot_surface` but I don't know how to do the 2D projection while having the colors changed.

Comment: Probably this is very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917495/matplotlib-imshow-in-3d-plot

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flat surface plot to mimic an imshow. I.e. you'd plot the surface with a constant value and set the color of the surface according to the data values.

This is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib

H=np.arange(0,100)
H=H.reshape(10,10) 

x,y = np.meshgrid(range(0,10),range(0,10))
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection=Axes3D.name)
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,H)

#plot 2D meshgrid here
cmap = plt.cm.plasma
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=H.min(), vmax=H.max() )
colors = cmap(norm(H))
ax.plot_surface(x,y,np.zeros_like(x), cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=colors, shade=False)
#make a colorbar
sc = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sc.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.show()
```

[image]